# Unable to locate textbox element in selenium web driver,please hep us?

Tags: selenium

The below is my html tag:

I used this link [travelcube](http://www.travelcube.com/uk/Home.jsp;jsessionid=D6BBAA9ECCBC5DB37C8F774220CE157A.01IJW?page=CurrencyUL.jsp&siteid=viewtrip&lang=E)

and my html tag:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" size="10" name="amount">
```

to find text box element to automate in selenium web driver.  I am unable find web element for this text box, how to use code in java selenium web driver?

Comment: did we need to login to see this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to your Question:

The `textbox` is within a `frame`. So first you need to switch to the frame then locate the element and send the text as follows:

```
//your code lines
driver.switchTo().frame("Main");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='amount']")).sendKeys("10001");
//your next code lines
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks Debanjan... Same I have another query   , cant inspect and unable to locate this html link:

Comment: <img src="//www.travelcube.com/uk/viewtrip/E/images/buttons/go.gif" border="0" alt="GO" title="GO" onmouseover="return statusMsg(&quot;GO&quot;);" onmouseout="return hideMsg();">        ...can you have answer for this query?

Comment: @Suresh If my Answer have catered to your current Question can you Accept the Answer please and raise a new question with your new requirement. Our SO volunteers will be glad to help you out. Thanks